# ReactJS: How to test a state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quick question for `this.setState(...)` is obviously an asynchronous action and unit testing is synchronous, so how exactly are you ensuring that the result of a `setsState` in testing occurs successfully? IE the `setState` is setting the right values?

Are you doing it via a callback? Spy / Stub?

Just trying to figure out the best approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` receives an optional callback that is called once the `setState` method has finished. You can pass a handler for this event as a  `prop`.

For example, let's say that, everytime you type something on an `input`, the state should change. You could pass an `onInputChange` handler as a `prop` that is executed every time the state finished changing due to an input change. This event I mentioned only makes sense for `uncontrollable` components. If the component was `controllable`, the event would fire as I type, and it would be responsability of the `controller-component` to rerender the component as the result of an input change.

As for tests, unit tests are not necessarily synchronous.. Actually, in my case, I use the `done` callback a lot. Like this:

```
it('test something', (done) => { myModule.doSomething((error, success) => done()); });
```

The above example would work on `karma` and `mocha`, for example.

Comment: Well this does work, but can you do it without using the callback handler in setState? I'd like to avoid having to change the code to support tests.

Comment: I am afraid that, specifically for `uncontrollable` components, you cannot. The only way to acknowledge a state change would be to pass in this handler. There's no way of calling `setState` synchronously that I'm aware of. I just checked the docs again to be sure.

Comment: Ok got it, it just seems odd to always have to have to adjust your code in order to spy on what's going on without manually overriding setstate to see if it's called with the right data.